# property_exists() to check if static property exists inside class method

Tags: php, oop

I have a class with static properties and methods. One of my methods is a dynamic property grabber. I want to do this dynamically to prevent having a method for each property that I want to return. A single method would be nicer.

My problem is the method returns "Undefined Property". I have tried various solutions on the internet, but nothing seems to fit or work.

Class example:

```
class Generic
{
    public static $propA = "A";
    private static $propB = "B";
    protected static $propC = "C";

    public static function getProperty(string $property): string
    {
        if (!property_exists('Generic', $property)) :
            return "Undefined Property";
        endif;

        return self::$$property;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print_r(Generic::getProperty('propA'));
```

This returns as if the property does not exist. In fact, the visibility doesn't matter as they all return as if they don't exist. Additionally, I know this works when not using static variables. I would rather continue to use static variables.

Comment: Code looks to be working just fine? https://3v4l.org/u2g7K

Comment: I see the code is working in the link you supplied. This is strange behavior then, because the code is not working as expected on my test server. I wonder if it a setting/configuration in Laragon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating my code from above to include namespaces. This was the problem that was causing the method to return undefined.

The updated code is as follows:

```
class Generic
{
    public static $propA = "A";
    private static $propB = "B";
    protected static $propC = "C";

    public static function getProperty(string $property): string
    {
        if (!property_exists('JLDN\Generic', $property)) :
            return "Undefined Property";
        endif;

        return self::$$property;
    }
}

foreach (['propA', 'propB', 'propC', 'nonProperty'] as $prop) :
    printf("<p>Property: %s::%s - %s</p>\n", 'Generic', $prop, print_r(Generic::getProperty($prop), true));
endforeach;
```

Output:

```
Property: Generic::propA - A

Property: Generic::propB - B

Property: Generic::propC - C

Property: Generic::nonProp - Undefined Property
```